# Laravel 5.2 save user IP adress to DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying save user IP adress after login on website. I'm using laravel 5.2 framework. I got user table and login_ip row. My code looks like that:

```
$user = User::where('login_ip', Request::getClientIp());
$user->save();
```

But it does not saving. What i'm doing wrong? Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save IP for current user, you can do this:

```
auth()->user()->update(['login_ip' => Request::getClientIp()]);
```

This will not create additional query as code in `shoieb0101`, `Amit` and `Ronald` answers.

Don't forget to add `login_ip` to the [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) array in `User` model:

```
protected $fillable = ['login_ip'];
```

If you want to save IP for only logged in users and ignore guests, you can do a check:

```
!auth()->check() ? : auth()->user()->update(['login_ip' => Request::getClientIp()]);
```

Comment: Ok. Now i'm getting error 'Call to a member function update() on null'

Comment: @ромМакаров, it seems you're trying to run this code when there is not logged in user. If this is the case, wrap the code in `if (auth()->check()) { .... }`. Or use the ternary operator as in updated answer.

Comment: Ok,thanks now i'm not getting errors, but then i check login_ip in DB it's still empty. Seems like not saving ip to DB

Comment: @ромМакаров, did you add `login_ip` into `$fillable` array? If yes, what does `dd(Request::getClientIp());` show?

Comment: Really strange. After that i'm getting my IP on page

Comment: @ромМакаров, well yes, `dd(Request::getClientIp());` should show you an IP, so it's working. Did you add `login_ip` to `$fillable` array in `User.php`? I've just tested this code and it works perfectly.

Comment: I removed the "auth()->" and now works perfectly! Thanks matte!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as:

```
auth()->user()->login_ip = Request::getClientIp();
auth()->user()->save();
```

OR

```
auth()->user()->save(['login_ip' => Request::getClientIp()]);
```

*Note - It will update the user's `login_ip` in single query.*

Comment: Since Laravel always gets `User` instance for authenticated user, this approach will create redundant query, so when you use it, you'll get 2 similar queries instead of one.

Comment: Answer updated..to use `auth()-user()` as `client` model object. Now it will be done in a single query.

Comment: It will work also when you don't have `login_ip` in your `$fillable` array of `user` model.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
$user->login_ip = Request::getClientIp();
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

//assuming $userid is also requested

```
$user = User::where('id', $userid);
$user->login_ip = Request::getClientIp();
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to get logged `user` form `db`, all info about your `user` you have in `Auth::user()` so:

```
Auth::user()->login_ip = Request::getClientIp();
Auth::user()->save();
```

or

```
Auth::user()->login_ip = $request->ip();
Auth::user()->save();
```

but you need to have `Request $request` as parameter of your method.

Comment: but `Auth::user()` get the user object of logged in user.

Comment: @imrealashu, that's what OP wants: to save an IP of logged in user.

Comment: Sorry I'm misunderstanding may be but I did not understand the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably stating the obvious, but your first line...

$user = User::where('login_ip', Request::getClientIp());

... returns an Eloquent query builder, right?

So, a save() on this will never work?

$user = User::where('login_ip', Request::getClientIp())->first();

... will return an actual User (if in the DB), which makes save() also possible.

Or did you make a typo in your OP?